# WCF Service with non .net present client

Tags: wcf, soap, datacontract, xmlserializer, soapheader

Instead of creating a WCF service and a client by generated code of WSDL,  I must create a WCF service with a given SOAP request.

To help you better understand, I copied the main part of the SOAP request here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header>
    <HeaderContent xmlns="CustomerNamespace.com">
      <CallerId>6274</CompanyId>
      <Login>mylogin</Username>
      <Password>mypassword</Password>
      <ResponsibilityType>3</Responsibility>
      <ResponsibilityId>189281728</ResponsibilityId>
    </HeaderContent>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateNutritionalValues  xmlns="CustomerNamespace.com">
      <NutritionalValues>
        <Product id="195739241">
        <Created>2011-11-01</Created>
        <Owner>8633</Owner>
        .
        .
        .
```

So, my service will receive this SOAP request. The embedded `NutritionalValues` XML is very long and I cannot change anything at the soap request at all because our customer use this request for many other companies as well. 
And this is my problem.

1. How do I map the XML `NutritionalValues` content to my "DataContract"?
2. How do I access the Header to authenticate the caller?

When I debug my Service with a handcrafted generated SOAP request with Fiddler I receive a null parameter value

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="CustomerNamespace.com")]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ComplexType UpdateNutritionalValues(NutritionalValues nutVal);
}

[DataContract]
public class NutritionalValues
{
    [DataMember(Name="Product")]
    public ProductSpecification Product { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ProductSpecification
{
    [DataMember(Name="Created")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="Owner")]
    public int Owner { get; set; }
}
```

( I can deserialize the XML manually too ) but i dont know how to access the ( raw? ) XML.

I would be very thankful for any help !